# IIS Rewrite: why does IIS show the rewrite URL?

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I use IIS Rewrite Module. I have a few static files, and they are stored at

website/static/xyz/abc

I added IIS Rewrite rule as follows:

```
regular expression pattern:

xyz/.+

rewrite URL:

/static/{R:0}
```

First, if I type (with an ending /)

```
http://mysite/xyz/abc/
```

everything seems working just fine. The browser address bar shows exactly what I typed.

Second, If I type (without the ending /)

```
http://mysite/xyz/abc
```

the website still displays the content correctly, but the browser address bar changes to (by adding static and the ending /)

```
http://mysite/static/xyz/abc/
```

How can I make IIS not show /static in the second situation?

Thanks and regards.

**UPDATE**

Regular expression is used.

```
            <rule name="inauguralball">
                <match url="inauguralball(/.*)?" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/static/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual rule, copied from your web.config?

Comment: Brandon, I posted it as you requested it. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: The browser should not be changing the displayed URL in the address bar. That would only happen with a Redirect rule, not a Rewrite rule. Are you sure you don't have any other redirect rules in place that could be conflicting?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that direction. I removed all rewrite rules before and after this rule. With this only one rule, I still get http://mysite/static/inauguralball/ displayed in the browser bar. Tried a few different browsers. Same results. I also restarted the website and application pool. No change. This is really weird.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am at a loss. I put this rule in my own web.config and it works as it should, without placing the word "static" in the url. I still believe there must be some other reason why your URL is getting redirected instead of rewritten, like maybe something in the code, or multiple web.configs in a subfolder somewhere or something else.

Comment: Brandon, thanks sooo much for testing it out. "inauguralball" is a directory. There is a default file such as index.html beneath it. Is this the settings in your test? Could you please post your web.config as a reply (not comment here) for me to copy? I will choose your reply as the answer. I am using asp.net 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found your answer here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298408/EN-US. When you leave out the trailing slash and IIS finds a directory that matches your request, it performs a redirect for you. I believe this is where your redirect is coming from, thereby sending you to /static/inauguralball/. Notice that IIS has also added the trailing slash for you because it detected that directory exists.

Can you make sure that your hrefs always point to /inauguralball/ (with the trailing slash) so that IIS doesn't perform that automatic redirect for you?

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the info. That is what I guessed, but you gave the definitive answer. Thanks a lot!!!